# lot of errors during first project in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

hey guys i juz downloaded the android SDK on eclipse and there seem to be infinite errors and since this  is my first time , i hav no clue where to start plz help

```
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\renu\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 07:49:08 - appcompat_v7]
```

these are only a few of the errors there are a million more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the appcompat library jar only. What you need to do is "import" the library as a full project along with its resources so it is another project in eclipse.

After that you add it to your current project as a reference.

This error is happening because it can not find resources. Resources are not bundled with the jar file

Comment: By the way if this answer helps you , please accept it ( I noticed you are new SO user :) )

Answer (score 0):

The errors here maybe due to one of the following reasons :

1. You are using `appcompat-v7` library in your project and you forgot to open this library by double clicking on it in eclipse project
2. You have not imported the library and just copied the `jar` file into the `libs` folder of your project directory.

Make sure, you check both of the above issues and let me know if I can help you further..